# mongodb prevent array elements duplicate among documents

Tags: mongodb, constraints

Lets say I insert following sample document

```
   db.getCollection("test").insert({
      _id: new UUID(),
      name: "abc",
      tags: ["A", "B"]
   })
```

When I try to add another document with tag "B" in that again I need mongo to raise a constraint violation.

```
   db.getCollection("test").insert({
      _id: new UUID(),
      name: "pqr",
      tags: ["B", "C"]
   })
```

Is this possible

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible using a unique index.

This index ensures all elements in the array throughout all documents are unique.

```
db.getCollection('test').createIndex({ tags : 1},{ unique: true })
```

Check [Mulitykey](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-multikey/) indexes in MongoDB and it's constraints.

Comment: Did you get any error while creating index? Is your collection empty?